# PubSub topic with binary data to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

I'm expected to have thousands of sensors sending telemetry data at 10FPS with around 1KB of **binary** data per frame, using IOT Core, meaning I'll get it via PubSub. I'd like to get that data to BigQuery, and no processing is needed.

As Dataflow don't have a template capable of dealing with binary data, and working with it seems a bit cumbersome, I'd like to try to avoid it and go full serverless.

Question is, what's my best alternative?

I've thought about Cloud Run service running an express app to accept the data from PubSub, and using global variable to accumulate around 500 rows in ram, then dump it using BigQuery's `insert()` method (NodeJS client).

How reasonable is that? Will I gain something from accumulation, or should I just insert to bigquery every single incoming row?

Comment: Have you tried cloud composer. Here is a link for airflow DAG for pulling from PubSub Subs - https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/pubsub.html#pulling-messages-from-a-pubsub-subscription

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Streaming Ingestion

If your requirement is to analyze high volumes of continuously arriving data with near-real-time dashboards and queries, streaming inserts would be a good choice. The quotas and limits for streaming inserts can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#streaming_inserts).

Since you are using the Node.js client library, use the BigQuery [legacy streaming API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#bigquery_table_insert_rows-nodejs)'s `insert()` method as you have already mentioned. The `insert()` method streams one row at a time irrespective of accumulation of rows.

For new projects, the [BigQuery Storage Write API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api) is recommended as it is cheaper and has an enriched feature set than the legacy API does. The BigQuery Storage Write API only supports `Java`, `Python` and `Go`(in preview) client libraries currently.

#### Batch Ingestion

If your requirement is to load large, bounded data sets that don’t have to be processed in real-time, prefer batch loading. BigQuery batch load jobs are free. You only pay for storing and querying the data but not for loading the data. Refer to quotas and limits for batch load jobs [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs). Some more key points on batch loading jobs have been quoted from this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-explained-data-ingestion-cdc26a588d0).

> **Load performance is best effort**
>
> - Since the compute used for loading data is made available from a shared pool at no cost to the user,
>   BigQuery does not make guarantees on performance and available
>   capacity of this shared pool. This is governed by the fair scheduler
>   allocating resources among load jobs that may be competing with loads
>   from other users or projects. Quotas for load jobs are in place to
>   minimize the impact.
>
> **Load jobs do not consume query capacity**
>
> - Slots used for querying data are distinct from the slots used for ingestion. Hence, data
>   ingestion does not impact query performance.
>
> **ACID semantics**
>
> - For data loaded through the bq load command, queries will either reflect the presence of all or none of the data .
>   Queries never scan partial data.

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks. As my whole business logic is in NodeJS, I prefer to stick with it for know. Are there plans to port the Storage Write API to NodeJS as well?

Comment: Yes, as per this [pull request](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery-storage/pull/209), support for BigQuery Storage Write API for the Node.js client is being worked on. However, we cannot provide an ETA on the availability date.